# AssetImage() always picking base asset

Tags: flutter

`AssetImage()` is always picking the base asset instead of the one according to the device pixel ratio. Here's how I'm using it:

```
class HomeScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(image: DecorationImage(image: AssetImage('assets/home_screen/title.png'))),
        )
    );
  }
}
```

Here's what I have in pubspec.yaml:

```
  assets:
    - assets/home_screen/
    - assets/home_screen/2.0x/
    - assets/home_screen/3.0x/
```

I have `title.png` in each directory above. My device pixel ratio is 2.625, but `AssetImage` always picks `assets/home_screen/title.png`, not `assets/home_screen/3.0x/title.png`

Answer (score 0):

An image asset can refer to one or more resolution-specific variants. Try to specify only the base asset to `pubspec.yaml`:

```
assets:
  - assets/home_screen/title.png
```

Comment: Does it pick the expected one if you explicitly set the `assets/home_screen/3.0x/title.png` to the AssetImage? would you mind providing the three images you use?

Comment: Yes, if I explicitly specify the 3.0x image, that image is selected. I'll try to upload.